# Generating a MD5 Hash with Qt

Tags: qt, md5

I am trying to generate an MD5 hash with Qt.  The hash I generate needs to be compatible with other standard MD5 hashes generated with other languages such as PHP.

This code does not give me the desired results:

```
QString encodedPass = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(("myPassword"),QCryptographicHash::Md5));
```

The result is "Þ±SoHu÷Õ?!?¡¯×L" instead of "deb1536f480475f7d593219aa1afd74c".  Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

PHP gives it to you in hex, Qt in binary. Convert it to hex using [`QByteArray::toHex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toHex).

```
QString blah = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(("myPassword"),QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex())
```