# PHP crypt() to Qt

Tags: php, qt, cryptography, crypt

I'm currently learning Qt5 for GUI applications. My first project is to make an authentication script and connect it to our database.

The problem is the password column is populated by PHP's `crypt()`, which generates a hash string that starts with `$1$`.

(e.g. `echo crypt("password");` prints `$1$d41.iA3.$XfuFXpCJfxSduzidGnKBR0`

How do I use Qt to compare the password inputted in my GUI application to the password column in database that's generated by `crypt()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
Use a key derivation function for password storing.

---

PHP's `crypt()` is horrible to use from other programming languages, because

- it uses a strange way to mix salt and password, instead standard HMAC
- it has it's own base64 alphabet that needs to be re-implemented

Apart from that you're using plain md5 as a password hash algorithm.
Never use md5 for password hashing. [Read more](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/). [And more](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php). [And more](https://www.google.com/search?q=md5%20password%20hashing%20week%20security).

---

But let's get our handy dirty then.

1. The structure of `crypt()`s output is the following: [image] where algorithm `$1$` with no *algorithm options* means MD5.
2. The hashed password is [base64 encoded using a custom alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461800/can-you-convert-the-output-of-php-crypt-to-valid-md5). This can be archived by replacing the output of [QByteArray::toBase64()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toBase64) with PHPs alphabet

   `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/
   ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
   ./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

   or re-implementing base64 if performance matters.
3. As seen in the [md5_crypt.c](http://ftp.stu.edu.tw/FreeBSD/FreeBSD-stable/src/contrib/libpam/modules/pam_unix/md5_crypt.c) implementation, max. 8 chars of the *salt* are used (`d41.iA3.` is your case).
4. Then input for md5 is constructed as `foo = password || $1$ || salt` where `||` is the string concatenation. Use QByteArray as type for `foo`.
5. Calculae `md5(password || salt || password)` and call it `bar`.
6. Set `bar = '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0'`
7. Cut `length(password)` bytes from `bar` (in binary representation) and append it to `foo`. Repeat `bar` as often as needed if `length(password) > 16`.
8. Uff, let me quote the original source *Then something really weird...*

   ```
   for (j = 0, i = length(password); i; i >>= 1)
       if (i & 1)
           foo += bar[j]
       else
           foo += password[j]
   ```

   which I hope i ready properly from the source.
9. Run [md5 on QByteArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495281/generating-a-md5-hash-with-qt): `bar = md5(foo)`.
10. Do that

    ```
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        moo = ""
        if (i & 1) {
            moo += password
        }
        else {
            moo += bar
        }
        if (i % 3) {
            moo += salt
        }
        if (i % 7) {
            moo += password
        }
        if (i & 1) {
            moo += bar
        }
        else {
            moo += password
        }
        bar = md5(moo)
    }
    ```
11. Glue everything together: `$1$ || salt || $ || base64(bar)`.

Comment: MD5 can be secure *if* it is correctly applied within a Key Derivation Function, for instance, PBKDF2. Of course, it is still better to use a known good function such as one of the SHA-2 hash functions. For PBKDF2, SHA1 could be chosen because of wider availability and compatibility.

Comment: Hmm actually when I came here the database is already populated with thousands of users, I could recommend that, but is there no way to mimic the PHP crypt with QT? I mean generate the same hash string if the same string and salt is used? Thanks for replying btw.

Comment: I tried to collect all steps and updated the answer. Hope for the best. Feel free to correct ma answer where needed.